# How to fix visual studio autocomplete when typing for loops?

Tags: c++, autocomplete, visual-studio-2017

This has been really bugging me ever since I switched from VS 2015 to VS 2017.

Here's what's happening:
When I type this

```
for(int i = 0; i<v.size()
```

then add a semicolon, VS autocompletes the line to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<v.size());
```

This is clearly not what I want, since I still need to type the increment portion of the for loop.

How do I prevent autocomplete for this specifically?

Comment: Looks like the closing `)` is throwing off the auto parser.  You can turn off the Automatically format statement when I type a `;` but that probably isn't what you want to do.  As a work around you can use a ranged based for loop or a standard algorithm instead.

Comment: If you have a microsoft account, be sure to vote this issue up: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27757/auto-complete-adds-parentheses-at-the-wrong-place.html

Comment: Try range for loops

Answer (score 2):

It is strange that you are typing this manually. Have you tried using stock code snippets? Type `for` and you should get a popup with `for` snippet selected -> press Tab to insert body and autoselect index variable type -> type new type -> press Tab to select index variable name and so on; finally press Enter to jump into loop body.

[image]

Comment: @NathanOliver You can also write you own snippets.

Comment: It's a good solution, but it's certainly not strange to type a for loop manually. It's not like this snippet would save a significant amount of time in an editor that wasn't adding spurious parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug that was introduced in VS2017. Make sure to bump the [thread dedicated to this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27757/auto-complete-adds-parentheses-at-the-wrong-place.html), and hopefully this will encourage the VS team to prioritize fixing this bug in a future release.